# Aggregate numpy functions

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have a numpy operation that I call intensively and I need to optimise:

```
 np.sum(a**2, axis=1)**.5   # where a is a 2 dimensional ndarray
```

This operation is composed of three functions and requires iterating through 'a' three times. It would be more efficient to aggregate all operations under one function and apply that function just once along axis 1. Unfortunately, numpy's [apply_along_axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) function is not an option as performance is around x1000 worse.

Is there a way of aggregating several numpy operations so it only has to loop once over the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with floating-point array, you can use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,a))
```

Runtime test -

```
In [34]: a = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

In [35]: np.allclose(np.sum(a**2, axis=1)**.5,np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,a)))
Out[35]: True

In [36]: %timeit np.sum(a**2, axis=1)**.5
100 loops, best of 3: 7.57 ms per loop

In [37]: %timeit np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,a))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you. This is even better than I expected!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`numexpr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numexpr), which allows you to evaluate numerical expressions faster than pure `numpy`:

```
In [19]: a = np.arange(1e6).reshape(1000,1000)

In [20]: import numexpr as ne

In [21]: %timeit np.sum(a**2,axis=1)**0.5
100 loops, best of 3: 6.08 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit ne.evaluate("sum(a**2,axis=1)")**0.5
100 loops, best of 3: 4.27 ms per loop
```

The `**0.5` is not part of the expression because the `sum` is a reduction operations and needs to be computed last in an expression. You could also run another evaluation for the `sqrt`/`**0.5`.

Comment: `numexpr` as `sqrt` too, so maybe that could help to replace `**0.5`? Though that would mean nesting two `evaluate` calls probably.

Comment: The `sqrt`only took only about 1% of the time of the `sum`, so I thought it was a bit of needless optimization at that point.