# Time-efficient combination of numpy functions

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have two 3 dimensional numpy arrays A, B (size ~ (1000, 1000, 3) -> image processing) and the element-wise functions on it.

The functions are sequentially:

```
import numpy as np
A  = A ** 3
A = np.maximum(A, 0.001)
C = np.divide(B, A)
```

Since the function operating these 3 commands is the bottleneck of a time-demanding process, I would like to ask whether there is a way to perform all of those with a single access to each element in memory, i.e. the fastest performance.

The only combinations I could find was the divide part, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293614/divide-one-numpy-array-by-another-only-where-both-arrays-are-non-zero) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248654/numpy-return-0-with-divide-by-zero), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003322/aggregate-numpy-functions) which is a special case because of the einstein sum.

Is there any way to do that accessing each element in the memory one time (thus make it time-efficient) without the need to write a custom ufunc?

Comment: Datatype permitting, using the third link, do `np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk->ijk',A,A,A)` to simulate `A***3`? That should be really efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to do that accessing each element in the memory one time (thus make it time-efficient) without the need to write a custom ufunc?

Yes, this is exactly what [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide) was designed for.

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

def func1(A, B):
    A = A ** 3
    A = np.maximum(A, 0.001)
    return np.divide(B, A)

def func2(A, B):
    return ne.evaluate("B / where(A**3 > 0.001, A**3, 0.001)",
                       local_dict={'A':A,'B':B})

A, B = np.random.randn(2, 1000, 1000, 3)

print(np.allclose(func1(A, B), func2(A, B)))
# True
```

`numexpr` gives about a factor of 70 improvement over your original code:

```
In [1]: %%timeit A, B = np.random.randn(2, 1000, 1000, 3)
func1(A, B)
   ....: 
1 loop, best of 3: 837 ms per loop

In [2]: %%timeit A, B = np.random.randn(2, 1000, 1000, 3)
func2(A, B)
   ....: 
The slowest run took 8.87 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an
intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop
```

In part this is because `numexpr` will use multiple threads for the computation by default, but even with a single thread it still crushes naive vectorization:

```
In [3]: ne.set_num_threads(1)
Out[3]: 8

In [4]: %%timeit A, B = np.random.randn(2, 1000, 1000, 3)
func2(A, B)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 47.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: That speedup is just huge! Confirmed similar figures at my end.

Comment: Quite impressive indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, `numexpr` one-liner listed in [`@ali_m's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36959027/3293881) looks like the way to go, given the associated speedup numbers. Keeping things in NumPy, listed in this post is an alternative *suggestion*.

Let's time those instructions one at a time and see if there's any bottleneck -

```
In [108]: # Random input arrays
     ...: A = np.random.rand(1000,1000,3)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(1000,1000,3)
     ...: 

In [109]: %timeit A**3
1 loops, best of 3: 442 ms per loop

In [110]: A  = A ** 3

In [111]: %timeit np.maximum(A, 0.001)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop

In [112]: A = np.maximum(A, 0.001)

In [113]: %timeit np.divide(B, A)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.7 ms per loop
```

So, it seems the power calculation takes up a huge portion of the total runtime.

Let's  introduce [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) there, but please be aware that of the datatypes involved.

```
In [114]: # Random input arrays
     ...: A = np.random.rand(1000,1000,3)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(1000,1000,3)
     ...: 

In [115]: %timeit A**3
1 loops, best of 3: 442 ms per loop

In [116]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk->ijk',A,A,A)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.3 ms per loop

In [117]: np.allclose(A**3,np.einsum('ijk,ijk,ijk->ijk',A,A,A))
Out[117]: True
```

That's a good speedup there.